# Youtube video not autoplaying first time code is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, autoplay

I have this code:

```
$(".thumbnail_border img").live('click', function() {

   $('param[name="movie"]').val(function(i, oldVal) {
        return oldVal + (oldVal.indexOf('?') ? '&autoplay=1' : '?autoplay=1');
    });
    $('embed').attr('src', function(i, oldSrc) {
        return oldSrc + (oldSrc.indexOf('?') ? '&autoplay=1' : '?autoplay=1');
    });
});
```

which dynamically adds the code to the youtube embed code so that it autoplays. However, fresh off of a page reload, the first time this code is run, the code works correctly but the youtube video does not play automatically. However, the second time and so on after the code is run, the Youtube video is played automatically. Why is this and how can I get the youtube video to play automatically the first time as well?

Comment: Is your code wrapped in a `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: yeah, it's also wrapped in this: `$(".thumbnail_border img").live('click', function() {`